# Deploy KeystoneJS site without generator-keystone

Tags: node.js, npm, keystonejs

I have the entire set of sources of a site, based on **KeystoneJS**. I tried to deploy it to my laptop (without `generator-keystone`, because all required files are already generated), but even after

```
npm install
```

I got errors, like:

```
> node keystone.js

module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'methods'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

I have installed `methods`, and now it requires `utils-merge`.

How I could install **ALL** required packages???

ENV: Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm install -g npm
```

The reason was in outdated **NPM**.